# Problems with GameSalad games after HTML5 publishing

Tags: gamesalad

I published a prototype I'm working on so my friends can check it out (http://arcade.gamesalad.com/game/111017).
I have two problems:
1. The enemies goes lower and lower until they just slide on the ground
2. The player randomly loses the ability to shoot.

Neither of these problems occurs when I'm using the Preview button or the Web Preview button on my copy of GameSalad.
How am I suppose to debug a game when the final product doesn't match the development version?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **friction** and **bounciness** under *Physics* on your both actors Enemy and Ground. Lower the friction and increase the bounciness little by little to get the desired result.

If your Enemies start to bounce off too fast or too high, you can check the box **"Apply Max Speed"** under *Motion* and give it a max speed of, say, 300.